# VIH of digital selection inputs for analog Mux when supplied with 4096mV - CD4051 IC

Tags: sensor, multiplexer, 4-20ma, analog-switch

I will use CD4051BM96 part number, [DATASHEET](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4051b.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-digikeymode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1597348047035)

On page 7 is shown specs of VIH. It shows VIH of 3.5V for 5V supply (this 70% of VDD), VIH of 7V for 10V supply (70%) and VIH of 11V for 15V supply (73.3% of VDD).

I will supply the IC with 4096mV, then the VIH would be around 70% of 4.096V? Around 2.86V?

This is cause I will supply VDD with 4.096V and will put 3.3V of processor on channel selection pins.
If it is supplied with 4.096V of VDD and is put 3.3V on any selection pin, will it recognize as logic high?

OBS: My input voltage on each mux input can go up to 4.096V also.

Regards.

[image]

Comment: Vih (min) = 70% of Vdd at 25’C. This might drift lower or higher than the typical 50% and 70% worst case over full temp range. But 3.3/5V= 86.7% so there is adequate margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 3.3V is above the required level for logic high.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it will work, with reasonable margin, however the chip may draw more current because the input is not near the positive rail.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing out. I think the extra current consumption will not be a problem.